# How to get window to change on button click in c?

Tags: c, button, gtk, buttonclick

I'm using c and GTK to make a gui in c, and i'm unsure how to get the window to change when I click a button.

What I'm trying to do is use GTK button_get_event_window to change what is displayed in the window when button is clicked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see if you can focus your question down to a problem with specific code and errors.  Show us your relevent code, any errors, and what you have tried so far, and you'll have a much better chance of getting a good answer to your question.

Comment: You may try hiding current window and showing the new window containing form.

Comment: You need to look into GdkEvents. All aspects of the windows need to react to the mouse_clicked event. There is some issue with event masks, but to be honest I don't know much as the project I was trying to get something similar going is on pause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [GtkAssistant](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAssistant.html); it'll be like those "wizard" pages