# gtk - How to open a window and close the old window when i press a button in C?

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk3

I am new in gtk and I want to do a complete program with this GUI.
The problem here is how I open a window and close the old window, like if I press a button called "New window" I open a new window and I close or hide the old window and I can use the new one.

Here's some code to understand what I'm saying:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void fc_open_window(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer window)
{
  gtk_widget_hide(window);
  system("./NewWindow");
  gtk_window_destroy(window);
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *grid;
  GtkWidget *button;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
  
  grid = gtk_grid_new();
  gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(grid,true);
  gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(grid,true);

  gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), grid);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("New Window");
  g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(fc_open_window), window);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
  g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_window_destroy), window);
  gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);

  gtk_widget_show(window);

}

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new("gtk.main.window1", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068510/how-to-get-window-to-change-on-button-click-in-c
```

I use new functions using gtk_window_destroy(window) but nothing special. I try to put the code of "NewWindow" in a function but more of the same.
The code of the NewWindow it is like the gtk example-1.c in the official page(do you have the example here https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html).
If you have any idea of my problem please put it in the comments.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Calling `system` starts a new, unrelated process. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want close the current process and execute a new one

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int fc_open_window(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer window)
{
    GError *error = NULL;
    gchar *argv[] = {"NewWindow", NULL};

    if (!g_spawn_async(NULL, argv, NULL, G_SPAWN_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, &error)) {
        g_print("Error starting the new program: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free(error);
        return 1;
    }

  gtk_window_destroy(GTK_WINDOW(window));

}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *grid;
  GtkWidget *button;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
 gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");

 grid = gtk_grid_new();
 gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid),true);
 gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid),true);

 gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), grid);

 button = gtk_button_new_with_label("New Window");
 g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(fc_open_window), window);
 gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 0, 1, 1);

 button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
 g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_window_destroy), window);
 gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), button, 0, 1, 2, 1);

 gtk_widget_set_visible(window,TRUE);

}
```

To launch a program from within a GTK application,
g_spawn_async() is the means of choice.

However, you have to make sure that a different application ID is used for the program you want to start. Otherwise, there will be problems with the registration on the D-Bus.